# Java : How to capture Image from webcam on motion detection

Tags: java, image-processing

I am working on a project where I want to capture an Image on motion detection using Webcam.

Initially I want to start with USB cam and later I want to Integrate the same for IP camera. So please point me to the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: who are you going to spy on huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this [Library](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) which has nice samples as well. The samples are sorted with respect to their functionality. You can integrate the functionality and get the desired result. I case you need help with code or stuck somewhere you can ask.

Comment: Once you do setup for the project you can implement `WebcamMotionListener` and get the pictures on motion detection.